# Trying to make an .exe out of a python code that uses pyfiglet and some prints with flush

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pyinstaller, cx-freeze, flush

I am fairly new in Python and no real experience with other languages. I am finishing an initiation course on this language and I am now working on my final project.
I am using PyCharm and running Python 3.8.

My program uses `pyfiglet` for some ascii art style intro.
Time module to simulate some basic animations.
This bit of code seems to have banned me from getting an .exe file. I try it but when I want to run it, it immediately closes the cmd. It is not even letting me input the first bit of information the program needs to start running.

```
print("Setting up plugboard connections...")
plug_amount = len(key[0][0])
for i in range(plug_amount):
    print(key[0][0][i], " ", end="", flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.3)
    for k in range(12):
        print("-", end="", flush=True)
        time.sleep(0.1)
    print(" ", key[0][1][i], " ", flush=True)
print("Done!")
time.sleep(0.5)
```

Before that bit was present, pyinstaller and cx_freeze from [this tutorial](https://www.activestate.com/blog/how-to-convert-py-to-exe/) worked. Now it does not work and I really want to share this program with friends regardless of the course.
How can I solve this problem?

EDIT:

This is the traceback I get when I run the exe from the cmd

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 359, in get_provider
KeyError: 'pyfiglet.fonts'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "enigma.py", line 179, in <module>
      File "enigma.py", line 9, in main
      File "site-packages\pyfiglet\__init__.py", line 65, in figlet_format
      File "site-packages\pyfiglet\__init__.py", line 794, in __init__
      File "site-packages\pyfiglet\__init__.py", line 801, in setFont
      File "site-packages\pyfiglet\__init__.py", line 126, in __init__
      File "site-packages\pyfiglet\__init__.py", line 136, in preloadFont
      File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1134, in resource_exists
      File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 361, in get_provider
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyfiglet.fonts'
    [13684] Failed to execute script enigma
```

Edit 2:
This is what I get after I try rebuilding as `pyinstaller enigma.py --hidden-import=pyfiglet.fonts`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "enigma.py", line 179, in <module>
  File "enigma.py", line 9, in main
  File "site-packages\pyfiglet\__init__.py", line 65, in figlet_format
  File "site-packages\pyfiglet\__init__.py", line 794, in __init__
  File "site-packages\pyfiglet\__init__.py", line 801, in setFont
  File "site-packages\pyfiglet\__init__.py", line 126, in __init__
  File "site-packages\pyfiglet\__init__.py", line 136, in preloadFont
  File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1134, in resource_exists
  File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1404, in has_resource
  File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1472, in _has
NotImplementedError: Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type
[12620] Failed to execute script enigma
```

Comment: Open a command prompt, navigate to the directory of the executable generated with PyInstaller, and run it. What's the traceback?

Comment: @Legorooj I'll add it to the post

Comment: `--hidden-import=pyfiglet.fonts`?

Comment: @Legorooj I don't understand what you mean by that...

Comment: build the executable with that option.

Comment: aaaand...how should I do that? `pyinstaller enigma.py --hidden-import=pyfiglet.fonts` ?

Comment: yes, build like that.

Comment: @Legorooj Now I am getting this new error `NotImplementedError: Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type`

Comment: Can I have the full traceback again? In another edit.

Comment: @Legorooj There it is

Comment: I'll look into fixing this. You've discovered a "bug" - or, more accurately, a feature that was never fully implemented. I've added a commit to my pyinstaller fork and will see if that works.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I went in and did some digging myself and I saw people having the same problem with no solutions yet.

Comment: I've done some more looking into this. This will require a bigger fix, so I opened https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4881 to track this. I'll get to work on a fix. In the meantime, the fastest way to get this resolved would be to submit a PR to pyfiglet itself, that doesn't use pkg_resources to load the fonts. (Unless of course I end up fixing this tommorow. But that's unlikely. pkg_resources is a nightmare)

Comment: @Legorooj That's very kind of you. Luckily I can still finish my final project without that feature but I'm sure that once it is fixed it will be very helpful for all fellow coders out there.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
pyinstaller --add-data "C:/Python36/Lib/site-packages/pyfiglet;./pyfiglet" --onefile  C:\Python36\work\myfile.py
```